# How to save data in Listview and show current date with it

Tags: android, listview, calendar, sharedpreferences

I am making an app where it counts touch on the screen. I can save the data on textview,, but i want to save the data to listview so it keeps on increasing as the data is saved. I also want to show current date next to number of click on same listview.
For Example:

06-May-2014: You touched 6 times

---

07-May-2014: You touched 9 times

For touch on screen I am using this code:-

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        try {



            if (nearCount >=0 ) {

                tv.setText("" + nearCount++);


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);

}
```

Do I have to use shared preference to store the data when the app is closed??

Answer (score 0):

First store the touch items in Arraylist and add the arraylist to listview and refresh the listview using `list.notifyDataSetChanged()` on every touch

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        try {

            nearCount=nearCount+1;

            if (nearCount >=0 ) {


                list_array.add(""+nearCount);
                 CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,list_array);

                 list.setAdapter(adapter); 
                 list.notifyAll();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you give me link to a tutorial bcoz i am new to using listview so have no idea about it. And also how to show current dates on listview.

Comment: and also do i have to use shared preference to store the data??

Comment: No need of shared prefernces and for lisview you can refer : http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/